# How to combine texts values from multiple rows into a single cell in access queries

Tags: microsoft-access

Can You Please help me in doing this: 
Please look at images below

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did that fail? What has your research so far shown as a possible solution?

Comment: Use a query that groups/sums the `Discount` column, and see [Concatenate fields from one column in one table into a single, comma delimited value in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600637/concatenate-fields-from-one-column-in-one-table-into-a-single-comma-delimited-v).

Comment: I think its work but I can't understand who to apply this function can you please provide me with a video or more understandable way to do this.

Comment: I made the function ConcatRelated()

Comment: but can you please help me in write the select statemet for my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you now have the [ConcatRelated() function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html), you can use this query, which simply sums the `Discount` column for all rows, and uses `ConcatRelated` to concatenate the `Reason` values for all rows:

```
SELECT Sum(Discount) AS Total_Discounts
     , ConcatRelated("Reason", "Table1") AS The_Reasons
FROM Table1;
```

If you would like the query to create the `Table2` table from your second screenshot, just add an `INTO` clause:

```
SELECT Sum(Discount) AS Total_Discounts
     , ConcatRelated("Reason","Table1") AS The_Reasons
INTO Table2
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Can you please answer to my question, i posted it in a new answer.
I will be thankful for you man

Comment: If I answered your question, please [accept my answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also, a follow-up question that is too long to be posted as a comment should be posted as a new question, not as an answer to the original question. That is most likely the reason your "answer" was [deleted](http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). Once you have posted a new question, you can provide a link to it in another comment here, and that way I will be alerted to it.

Comment: Ok, Thank you I Accepted you answer It was The best answer for this question and its work. 
I will post a new question and provide you with the link here.
Thank you again :)

Comment: I Post a new question. This is the link of the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861552/how-to-combine-texts-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-cell-in-access-quer